# array_slice with negative offset on huge arrays

Tags: php, arrays

For reason that I'll not discuss here, I'm forced to parse a large directory of files (we are talking 100.000 < x < 1.000.000+) and return the filelist as an array.

I'm already caching the file list, the problem is [array_slice](http://php.net/array_slice).

Yes, because there is a catch, this list of file must be "paginated" returning them in block of 16.

What I'm doing is this:

```
$items_per_page = 16;
$offset = ($current_page * $items_per_page) + $items_per_page;
array_slice($array,-$offset,$items_per_page);
```

It's easy to see that in a few pages we'll have huge offsets.
Also starting from page four (offset = -80) there is a huge performance hit.

What could I use instead of array_slice to achieve this sort of array pagination?

Thanks

Comment: 100k files in **one** directory is just wrong implementation...

Comment: Yes it is, very wrong. But this is what I have to work with, it's not my choice, after the deadline I'll be sure to change this mess.

Comment: Using `preserve_keys` might help (not sure though). `array_slice($array,-$offset,$items_per_page, true);`

Comment: If the array is cached, can you just cache it in smaller chunks over multiple files? Then based on the page, calculate which file it is in and offset from that.

Comment: Caching it in smaller files will still require the same computation power because I still have to seek and divide the array in chunks. Since this horror need to rebuild the cache every 5 minutes is not a viable solution (unless I'm missing something).

Comment: @Matt Ball: yes there is a substantial improvement when preserving the keys, but it still dies when calculating larger offsets.

Comment: Not missing anything, you just didn't mention it would need to be rebuilt so often.

Comment: Is the array keyed numerically/sequentially? If so, it might be easier to do a loop and copy out 16 elements into a new array instead of slicing out a chunk.

Comment: @Marc B: yes, it is indeed sequential.. uhm interesting..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the array is numerically indexed (without skipping numbers) you could try to use a for loop.

```
$items_per_page = 16;
$offset = ($current_page * $items_per_page) + $items_per_page;
$chunk = array();
for($i=$offset;$i<$offset+$items_per_page;$i++){
    $chunk[] = $files[$i];
}
```

Edit:

I just did some benchmarking to get an idea. On our server, with an array of 1 million items, processed 100 times each, array_slice() took 2.5689ms to process. Using a for loop took 0.0031ms.

Comment: Thanks. If people see this. The solution is perfect unless for a single thing, the first page (0) the offset must be 0. So: if ($current_page >0){ $set = ($current_page * $items_per_page) + $items_per_page;} else { $offset = 0; }

Comment: @0plus1 There is a problem with the way you calculate the offset. page 1 would get you 1*16=16+16=32. page 0 would get you 0. You would never see the 16-31 results. The correct way to get the page would be something like: `$offset=(($current_page-1)*$items_per_page)%count($data);`

Answer (score 6):

Consider creating, filling and manipulating a DB table instead of doing all of this in memory. An index on it will allow you to paginate the files with reasonable performance.

Comment: That is the last resort if all else fails.. still I would like to find a viable solution to improve my knowledge.

Comment: Jonathan's suggestion should be faster for access, but you'll still need to populate (and possibly sort?) the crazy sized array...

Comment: Agreed @ what Denis just said. Using a database would be 1000's of times better, faster, easier and allow you to do much more like sorting and searching. Which is why this gets my vote.